# Push notifications not being received by Android or iOS physical or emulator/simulator devices

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification

My project heavily relies on push notifications or FCM messages for VoIP & messaging features. The issues is these notifications aren't being received by any device when sending a cloud-messaging test message.

---

**Project on Github** to view code directly (excluding GoogleServices files): [Github Here](https://github.com/cybex-dev/android-ios-push-notification-example)

---

Creating a fresh flutter project + firebase project, I performed the following steps:

- Create Flutter project, using `com.company.pushnotifications`  + add firebase & messaging deps ([ref](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview#2-download-dependency))
- Created a Firebase project
- Create [Android Firebase App, download `GoogleServices.json`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#register-app) and place into `android/app` folder + add required `android/build.gradle` + `android/app/build.gradle` plugins ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file))
- Create [iOS Firebase App, download `GoogleService-Info.plist`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#register-app), copy into [Runner folder using Xcode specifically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add-config-file).
- Configure iOS [app identity](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#2-registering-an-app-identifier) + [provisioning profile](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#3-generating-a-provisioning-profile) + [APNS key (installed into Firebase Cloud Messaging) with Push notifications](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#linking-apns-with-fcm) + [enable Background (fetch + notification) capabilities](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#enable-background-modes-ios-only) & [push notifications capabilities](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#enable-push-notifications)
- [do not swizzle notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging) by adding the following to the `Info.plist` file:

`Info.plist` file:

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled -> NO (Boolean)
```

- edit `ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift` with the following content:

`AppDelegate.swift` content:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase // added this line

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure() //add this
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

- Setup firebase messaging with the following flutter code:

I'm debugging with breakpoints in background & foreground messages, left it for 2 hours incase the messages were delayed but on not one of the debugging sessions did a breakpoint trigger indicating a message was received

`main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();  // breakpoint for debugging placed here

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseApp defaultApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // source: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // source: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!'); // breakpoint for debugging placed here
    print('Message data: ${message.data}');

    if (message.notification != null) {
      print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
    }
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

When sending a test push notification using Cloud Messaging Test notifications, I expect the notification to show on Android (emulated or physical atleast), but it does not show on either iOS or Android (emulated or physical).

To my knowledge I've followed the documentation as required - did I miss something or is something broken?

Comment: iOS will never receive push notifications with emulators. Android emulators require Google APIs and a connected account.

Make sure both devices are in background to receive the push notifications on physical devices. Make sure your SHA1 and SHA256 are in. Make sure the "APNs Auth Key" from App Store Connect is loaded over Firebase.

iOS requires user request permission to send push notifications.

Are you trying to send from Firebase backend?

Comment: if you're using a backend, you need to specify the device token id when you send the push... if not, you need subscribe to topics to be able to get the push notifications

Comment: is your main AndroidManifest not being used? Because you don't have Internet Permissions over there... only debug and profile.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla (1st comment) - test with internet permission, no difference. Sha1 hashes? (to my knowledge this was never a requirement i.e. optional). APN key has been added as mentioned. Don't think I asked for permission to send push notifications but all capabilities, etc have been added and finally as mentioned I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging's Test Notifications to send Push Notifications

Comment: tested all apps (physical + simulator) in foreground & background - no push notifications were shown

Comment: Android normally is the easy test as you need to make sure it matches the json file with your project, AndroidManifest with the intent. Is this debug build, release mode or fully signed app?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I run this in debug mode to test if notifications come through - the primary purpose of this question. I see after some time, with app in background, notifications comes through. I sent a Firebase Cloud Messaging test notification and 1.5 hrs ago, it finally arrived in short succession by another (I sent and hour ago).